# No voice output using pyttsx in tkinter after cx_freeze

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze, pyttsx

I am using pyttsx to convert text to audio which works fine before compiling with cx_freeze. But after it gets converted to exe, there is no sound output. Even it produces no error. My setup file is following:

```
.
.
.
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("version2.py", base=base)]
includes = ['pyttsx', 'pyttsx.drivers.sapi5']
packages = ['tkinter']

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "SpellChcker",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages": packages, 'includes': includes}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Spelling check app",
    executables = executables
    )
```